# Yii Routes are not redirecting

Tags: regex, yii, routes

I'm having some trouble with the routing rules in Yii. I currently have a users controller that at the action for updating two sections of account information.

```
class UsersController extends CController {
    public actionAccount() {
    //Do Stuff
    }

    public actionAccountFindMe() {
    //Do More Stuff
    }
```

}

Now in my url manager I have the following rules in place:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'rules'=>array(
                'account'=>'users/account',
                'account/findme'=>'users/accountfindme',
            ),
        ),
```

The rule for /account works perfectly fine, but the rule for 'account/findme' always throws an error:

```
Error 404
Unable to resolve the request "account/findme".
```

What is this error being thrown and why is the pattern not matching?

P.S. I am able to access the route if I type in /users/accountfindme .

Comment: try with "account_findme" instead of "account/findme"

Comment: than try removing the first rule and leave the second to test

Comment: Hmm, removed the first rule and the second rule still doesn't work. What could cause that?

Comment: realy strange if you type u go to users/accountfindme it change your url to account/findme ?

Comment: try this maybe '<controller:account>/<action:findme>' => '/users/accountfindme'

Comment: I know, I'm head-to-desk right now. No that didn't even, I even tried the working route : 'account/findme'=>'users/account', and that doesn't work. Its like if I try to add a '/' the whole system doesn't work.

Comment: your controller and action are account and findme ? if no may be you need to switch keys and values :)

Comment: yes they are. I tried 'sidux/findme'=>'users/account' and still no . Logically the mathing url should route.

Comment: and with 'users/account'=>'sidux/findme ?'

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is related to the lack of capitalization for your action:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'rules'=>array(
                'account'=>'users/account',
                'account/findme'=>'users/accountFindMe', <-- capitalized to match your action
            ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have misconfigurated urlManager component. At least, you should set urlFormat to "path". Example of right urlManager:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'baseUrl'=>'',
    'rules'=>array(
         // your rules
    ),
),
```